# Analyze networks which are not scale free

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, gephi, cytoscape

I am trying to analyze the graph constructed with networkx having around 7000 nodes. When I plot the degree distribution there are nodes that are far away from the fitted power law as shown in the attached plot. This means the network is not scale-free (to my understanding). I am trying to analyze this network by using various parameters such as Degree, clustering coefficient, betweenness centrality, and many others. Does analyzing such networks with these parameters is acceptable? I try to find some examples of analyzing networks that are not scale-free but no luck so far. Any suggestions and pointer for such examples would be really great. In addition, some differences in network characteristics of scale-free and non-scale free networks would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. What type of model did you constructed? Did you use a data from a file?**

**2. What do you want to check?**

Models such as Watts-Strogatz (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts%E2%80%93Strogatz_model) is also no scale-free :

> `'They do not account for the formation of hubs. Formally, the degree
>   distribution of ER graphs converges to a Poisson distribution, rather
>   than a power law observed in many real-world, scale-free
>   networks.[3]'`

WS is a 'small-world' network. It is characterized by high clustering coefficient. Why you think you can't analyze it?

Comment: Hi Donka, Thank you so much for your response. I use networkx to construct the graph and is visualized by using Gephi (Force atlas 2 algorithm). Yes, the graph was written in a file as columns with "source", "target",  and weight of the edges. I am new to this os I just wanted to make sure I am doing it in the right way. Whenever I search I only found scale free networks. Thanks alot for the link.

Comment: If you want to study networks, I recommend: "Networks: An Introduction" Mark Newman.